# How to install libxml2 package in R if it's not available for my version?

Tags: r, libxml2, bioconductor

I wanted to install "DESeq2" package in R, but it was missing the xml2-config file. I found somewhere that it can be obtained by installing the libxml2 package, but when I tried it gives error that it's not available for R version 3.4.2. Anyone has idea what to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the dev version: `devtools::install_github("r-lib/xml2")`

Comment: OK!! Although indirectly but it did help! I write in the answer what I did.

Comment: I am happy that you solved your problem :)
If you think that the answer was useful you can consider to upvote it

Answer (score 3):

After running what @amarchin wrote it didn't work instantly but R suggested to install libxml2-dev. So I run: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` in Terminal. 
And then in R console I typed the code from @amarchin: `devtools::install_github("r-lib/xml2")`
And it worked :)